# Cannot Read JSON from local using pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am new to using PySpark. I am trying to read a local file, but it says file not found while the path is correct.

Here is my code

```
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Our first Python Spark SQL example") \
    .getOrCreate()

path = "data/sparkify_log_small.json"
user_log = spark.read.json(path)
```

The error

```
AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/Users/rito/Desktop/Projects/[Learning]_Spark/Spark_Wrangling/data/sparkify_log_small.json;
```

My SparkContext config

```
[('spark.app.name', 'Our first Python Spark SQL example'),
 ('spark.driver.host', '192.168.1.15'),
 ('spark.rdd.compress', 'True'),
 ('spark.driver.port', '50343'),
 ('spark.app.id', 'local-1609591208458'),
 ('spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', '100'),
 ('spark.master', 'local[*]'),
 ('spark.submit.pyFiles', ''),
 ('spark.executor.id', 'driver'),
 ('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client'),
 ('spark.ui.showConsoleProgress', 'true')]
```

Comment: Spark can't seem to handle file paths with square brackets. try renaming your folder `learning spark`?

Comment: @mck  ah live saver, it works now

Comment: Where did you get the file `sparkify_log_small.json` from?